# objective c compiler error

Tags: objective-c, compilation

I am trying to compile my project but the process continually fails with the following error:

```
ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_house_regions in /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/apptitle-alexsszihsvwirciwtciskwavrbg/Build/Intermediates/apptitle.build/Debug-iphoneos/apptitle.build/Objects-normal/armv7/munro_regions-77CBC76A.o and /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/apptitle-alexsszihsvwirciwtciskwavrbg/Build/Intermediates/apptitle.build/Debug-iphoneos/apptitle.build/Objects-normal/armv7/house_regions-77CBC76A.o for architecture armv7
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

I have looked in my **house_regions.m** and **.h** files to see if there is anything but I am not sure  what i am even looking for what is `_OBJC_CLASS`?

Do i need to supply any more information for this to make sense to people? I really don't know.

Comment: I'm guessing you have the same function name or property declared in multiple files.  I would search the project for the property names and methods in your house_regions class and see if any duplicates are found.

Comment: Please show the file `munro_regions.m`. As mackworth correctly identified, this file could contain the problem (and the solution).

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it's saying that you defined a class named "House_Regions" in both the file "munro_regions" and the file "house_regions"

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate symbol means that there is a double inclusion.Without seeing the code I can't guess what's wrong.
Maybe you used the include directive instead of import.So that file is included more than one time and it finds duplicate definitions.